# How to access data in firebase from react-native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I am having trouble rendering data from firebase.

Here is my current data structure on firebase:
{name: "sleep"} 
ie. that's the only object the database contains atm.
Using a ListView, it renders a row (shows the background and border of the row according to the number of items in the database), however, there is no text inside the row..

### ListView code:

```
             <ListView
              enableEmptySections={true}
              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
              renderRow={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
               />

  _renderItem(task) {
    return (
    <ListItem task={task} />
    );
  }
```

### Code for ListItem:

```
class ListItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <Text style={styles.listItemTitle}>{this.props.task.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

### Code used to listen to tasks

```
listenForTasks(tasksRef) {
  tasksRef.on('value', (dataSnapshot) => {
    var tasks = [];

    dataSnapshot.forEach((child) => {
      tasks.push({
        name: child.val().name,
        _key: child.key
      });

console.log(dataSnapshot.val()); // returns JSON object of {name: 'sleep'}
console.log(tasks); // returns an array containing the object of {name: 'sleep'}
console.log(dataSnapshot.val().name); // returns 'sleep'

    });

    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tasks)
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: In the render method of your `ListItem`, can you `console.log(this.props)` just to validate that it is getting the value from the dataSource?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a constructor for your ListItem Component:

```
class ListItem extends Component {

//Add this....
constructor(props){
   super(props)
}
//--------------

  render() { 
     return ( <View style={styles.listItem}>
        <Text style={styles.listItemTitle>
        {this.props.task.name}
        </Text>
      </View> ); 
  } 
}
```